# Why JDK Thread StackSize is 0?

Tags: java, multithreading

When I read JDK Thread class , I find the Thread Default Constructor new Thread() init method set stackSize=0,why?

```
 public Thread() {
    init(null, null, "Thread-" + nextThreadNum(), 0);
}
```

Comment: You can find an answer to this kind of question yourself by looking up the ___Java API documentation___. Try to google ``jdk api thread``. And then you'll get for example [Thread (Java SE 11 & JDK 11)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html). The  API documentation contains other helpful information – so be sure to start there when looking for a Java API explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A value of 0 means that the value passed to the `this` call (not the `init` call) should be ignored. If you trace the calls further, you will find the following constructor whose JavaDoc tells you exactly that.

```java
    /**
     * ...
     * @param stackSize the desired stack size for the new thread, or
     *        zero to indicate that this parameter is to be ignored.
     * ...
     */
    private Thread(ThreadGroup g, Runnable target, String name,
                   long stackSize, AccessControlContext acc,
                   boolean inheritThreadLocals) {
```

Ignoring the value does not mean that the value is set to 0, but that the VM is free to choose it.